# Function is only running once

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

My function is only running once. It contains only css.

I'm trying to make the divider expand in the animation, when the class for added. I'm trying, but I can not. I need this jquery code to execute when a specific slide becomes active. Anyone have any idea how to do it?.
I'm trying to put this on the Materialize Slide.
I have the following JQuery code. He are simple.

**HTML**

```
 <section class="section-slide">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="lista-slider">
                    <img src="img/music10.jpeg" class="responsive-img"> 
                    <div class="caption center-align top-setting">
                        <h3>Text1</h3>
                        <div class="divider-cap divider"></div>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Test1</h5>   
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="slide-2 lista-slider">
                    <img src="img/music12.jpeg" class="responsive-img"> 
                    <div class="caption center-align center-setting">
                      <h3>Test 2</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="lista-slider">
                    <img src="img/music4.jpg" class="responsive-img"> 
                    <div class="caption right-align right-setting">
                      <h3>Text 3 </h3>
                      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Test 3</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="lista-slider">
                    <img src="img/music9.jpeg" class="responsive-img"> 
                    <div class="caption center-align">
                      <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
                      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(window).on('load', function(){    
        var slideDivider = $('.slider .divider-cap')
        var sliderList = $('.slider ul li:eq(0)')   

        if(sliderList.hasClass('active'))
        {
            slideDivider.addClass('divider')    
        }
        else{
            slideDivider.removeClass('divider')
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
  .section-slide .slider .top-setting .divider{
      width: 600px;
      margin: auto;
      animation: dividerAnim 1s 1;
  }

 @-webkit-keyframes dividerAnim{
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% {top: 600px;}
}

 @keyframes dividerAnim{
    0%   {width: 0px}
    100% {width: 600px;}
}
```

Comment: what is it you are trying to do? at the moment, you're saying "when the document loads, give the active slide the class divider -- otherwise remove the class divider." But "active" is never applied to any of the elements, from what I see.

Comment: Maybe just use the "active" class to trigger your animation, rather than the "divider" class. What makes slides "become active"? A working example might be helpful to clarify your question.

Comment: Why not use `.animate()`?

Comment: It looks like the OP is trying to use the Materialize framework, but we've not been given anything resembling enough information.

Comment: I wonder if Materialize fires any events when changing slides... I haven't found anything in the documentation.

Comment: I already tried to use animation ... but I did not succeed.

Comment: in .animate () the result was the same